# Why do i get xcodebuild fatal error module map file not found from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, swift-package-manager, jazzy

I have a project which uses SPM (and does not use cocoapods).
It compiles and runs fine.

I can run SwiftLint autocorrect from the command line and that works too.

However, when I try to run jazzy on it, I am getting this error:

> fatal error: module map file
>   '/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/buil
>   d/GeneratedModuleMaps/iphoneos/RealmCore.modulemap' not found

I went through many "fixes" for similar problems: I updated system preferences to allow terminal access to Developer Tools, etc.

[image: SPM Configuration]

The jazzy command works for my other projects, some of which use the SPM, which baffles me a bit. As a workaround, I will remove SPM and use carthage to create the Realm and RealmSwift frameworks I need.

For completists:

Command line invocation:

> 2     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
>   -target Answers -sdk iphoneos
>     3
>     4 Build settings from command line:
>     5     SDKROOT = iphoneos13.4
>     6
>     7 Resolve Package Graph
>     8
>     9 Resolved source packages:
>    10   Realm:
>   https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git @ 4.4.1
>    11   Alamofire:
>   https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git @ 5.1.0
>    12   RealmCore:
>   https://github.com/realm/realm-core @ 5.23.8
>    13
>    14
>    15 note: Using new build system
>    16 note: Planning build
>    17 note: Using build description from disk
>    18 CompileC /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/Realm.build/Release
>   -iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/arm64/collection_notifications.o /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/Realm/ObjectStore/src/collection_notifications.cpp
>   normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Realm' from project 'Realm')
>    19     cd /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa
>
> 20     export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>
> 21 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x c++ -target arm64-apple-ios8.0 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiag    nostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c++14
>   -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild    -session-file=/var/folders/by/cr9r24wn2fn47wpyjnrq73qc0000gn/C/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
>   -fmodules-validate-once-per-build    -session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -fmodule-name=Realm -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -    Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes
>   -Wno-return-type -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missin    g-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants
>   -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enu    m-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -    DSWIFT_PACKAGE -DREALM_SPM=1 -DREALM_COCOA_VERSION=@\"4.4.1\"
>   -DREALM_VERSION=\"5.23.8\" -DREALM_NO_CONFIG -DREALM_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR= -DREALM_ENABLE_ASSERT    IONS=1 -DREALM_ENABLE_ENCRYPTION=1 -DREALM_VERSION_MAJOR=5 -DREALM_VERSION_MINOR=23 -DREALM_VERSION_PATCH=8 -DREALM_VERSION_EXTRA=\"\" -DREALM_VERSION_STRING=\"5.23.8\" -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated    -declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-move -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autorel    easing -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-range-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fembed-bitcode-marker -I/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/Derive    dData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-core/src
>   -I/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrke
>   wvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/Release-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkew
>   vufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/include
>   -I/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePacka
>   ges/checkouts/realm-cocoa
>   -I/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/includ
>   e
>   -I/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/Realm/ObjectStore/src
>   -I/Users    /Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm
>   .build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64
>   -I/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/DerivedSources/arm64
>   -I/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnplue
>   j/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.    platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks
>   -fmodule-map-file=/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/
>   checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/GeneratedModuleMaps/iphoneos/RealmCore.modulemap
>   -DXcode -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/arm64/collection_
>   notifications.d --serialize-diagnostics
>   /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-
>   cocoa/build/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/arm64/collection_notifications.dia
>   -c /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/Realm/ObjectStore/src/collection_notifications.cpp
>   -o /Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/build/Realm.build/Release-iphoneos/Realm.build/Objects-normal/ar
>   m64/collection_notifications.o
>    22 fatal error: module map file
>   '/Users/Alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Answers-akfeigwudbzjrkewvufnejnpluej/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/buil
>   d/GeneratedModuleMaps/iphoneos/RealmCore.modulemap' not found
>    23
>   warning: Could not read serialized diagnostics file: Cannot Load File:
>   Failed to open diagnostics file (in target 'Realm' from project
>   'Realm')

Does anyone recognize these symptoms?

Comment: I was able to create my jazzy doc by removing the dependency of SPM and creating the frameworks Realm and RealmSwift using Carthage. I'll try via SPM once Xcode 11.5 is released (it is in Beta 2 right now). I'll update this page when I get a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, whoever just upvoted this - thank you! (it reminded me to come back to this and resolve it)

The solution (now) is simple - use the latest version of RealmSwift

[image: screenshot]

[image: SPM product url]

Notice the url in the "Location" column. That's all you need.

Delete whatever you are using that doesn't work.

Starting fresh, use the url:

```
"https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git"
```

and accept the defaults

In pictures:

[image: SPM Configure 1]

[image: valid url]