# How to get Jazzy to ignore Swift Packages

Tags: xcode, documentation-generation, jazzy

I'm trying to use Jazzy on a project that uses a Swift Package but it fails because of the package. Does anyone know how to get it to ignore them. I've tried a number of options, but none work.

Comment: I might be able to help you out... Could you provide some details? Which package? Does the project compile ok? What did you try (what were the errors). The more context you provide, the more likely someone is going to be able to help you out.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and was able to solve it by deleting all packages and reinstalling them. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61701274/why-do-i-get-xcodebuild-fatal-error-module-map-file-not-found-from-command-line/62816430#62816430